# SAAB 9-5 automatic transmission warning

Tags: automatic-transmission, warning-light, saab

I recently had the aux drive belt fail on my SAAB 95. Because the alternator was then not running, the electrics all slowly died as the battery ran flat. As I was stopping I shifted into neutral and there was a "clunk" so I shifted back into Drive and there was another "clunk".

The drive belt is now repaired but I have a warning light for "Automatic Transmission" (a yellow gear wheel with an exclamation mark inside). The car drives fine and I don't think there's anything actually wrong at this point. Would this warning just linger until manually cleared? Is there a way of resetting it?

Update:
Sorry, I forgot to mention: the battery has been disconnected for at least 3 days while I recharged it off the vehicle. The light is still on when I reconnected the battery. It came on immediately on turning the ignition on and before starting the engine.

Comment: This should be an OBDI vehicle. You should be able to reset the codes by unplugging the battery for about 20-30 minutes. This should wipe all the codes out from the PCM. It'll most likely wipe your radio station presets as well, so be cognizant of this.

Comment: It's EOBD2 I believe. Sorry, I forgot to mention: the battery has been disconnected for at least 3 days. The light is still on when I reconnected the battery. It came on immediately on turning the ignition on and before starting the engine.

Comment: What model and engine? I assume by 95 you mean the year 1995. You should also find out which transmission model you have. You should also take the car to a shop to get the codes read, IIRC there isn't any way to pull the codes without a scantool.

Comment: No, the 9-5 is a model number, which was made in '95, and should not be confused with the model 95 which was not made in '95.

Comment: What year 9-5 is this?  Definitely read the codes and let us know. You can often borrow a code reader at an auto-parts store.

Comment: I didn't drive the car for a couple of days and the light went off by itself the next time I started the engine. My guess is that this was a "glitch" introduced by the power failure as the battery died and the fault cleared itself when the problem didn't reoccur.

Answer (score 1):

To bring this to a close, the light went off by itself and so problem solved.

Removing the battery for several days didn't fix the issue. The car started and drove OK but the light remained on.

After the initial test, I didn't drive the car for a couple of days and the next time I started it the light was gone.

So it looks like this was some sort of false alarm, maybe triggered during the power failure as the battery died.